# Making a variable value constant in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, constants

I'm very new to coding in android, so I barely know any of the syntaxes. I am defining a variable in MainActivity.java and assigning it a random 4 digit value. I want to assign this value only once, when the app is installed/updated, and not every time the user opens the app. Help me out if any of you know a fix for this. The following is my current code

```
Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(9999 - 1) + 1;
```

Comment: Use Shared Preference for storing value

Comment: try `SharedPreference`

Comment: Can you share how to that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference for saving value use this code

```
int i1=0;
 if (getIntValue() == 0) {
            Random r = new Random();
            i1 = r.nextInt(9999 - 1) + 1;
            saveIntValue(i1);
        } else {
            i1 = getIntValue();
        }
```

here are two method

```
public void saveIntValue(int myIntValue) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("your_int_key", myIntValue);
    editor.commit();

}

public int getIntValue() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", 0);
    if (myIntValue == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return myIntValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Store in Preference if value is 0 else get stored value

```
Random r = new Random();
    int value= r.nextInt(9999 - 1) + 1;

if(getValue()==0)
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                     .putInt("uniqueInt", value).apply();
    else {
        int uniqueIntFromPref = getValue();
    }
```

> Retrieve from Preference

```
private int getValue() {
            return  PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                    .getString("uniqueInt", 0);
        }
```

Just copy and paste above code

Answer (score 0):

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString("key for value", somrRandonNumber);
editor.putBoolean("is first lunch", false);
    editor.commit();
```

Then retrive it with

```
int number = sharedPref.getInt("key for value";
```

Sometimes you need to specify a default value like:

```
SharedPref.getBoolean("is first lunch",true);
```

Good luck